# Internet Explorer 8 in Ubuntu

Tags: wine, browser, ie

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install MS Internet Explorer 7, 8 or 9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64788/how-to-install-ms-internet-explorer-7-8-or-9)

Is it possible to get IE8 running in Ubuntu? It seems quite feasible to me, as I had gotten IE7 to run via Wine awhile back after reading a blog tutorial. However, for some reason that seems to be broken now, and I'd like to upgrade it anyway in order to test my web development endeavors more thoroughly.