# How to install MS Internet Explorer 7, 8 or 9?

Tags: wine, browser

I recently started using Ubuntu 11.4 as my primary OS. I’m trying to find a way to run Internet Explorer on it.

Is there a way to install on Linux/wine IE7 or higher versions? I saw only ie4linux which contains ie6...

The problem is on browsershots and similar serviece that the code must be confidential so I need some intranet solution without passing screens to other companies