# How to install Internet Explorer?

Tags: 11.10, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install MS Internet Explorer 7, 8 or 9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64788/how-to-install-ms-internet-explorer-7-8-or-9)

any body can tell me how can i install  ms internet explorer on my Ubuntu 11.10.I tried it by following two ways
wget http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/downloads/ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf ies4linux-latest.tar.gz
cd ies4linux-*
./ies4linux

I have also installed following two packages too
sudo apt-get install wine
sudo apt-get install cabextract

but it fails to install