# How can I view Ms-Office 2007 built-in help on Ubuntu 12?

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm running Ms Office on Ubuntu 12 using Wine 1.4. Everything is working fine , except the built-in help. I'm unable to see anything in the help dialogues.

How can I solve this issue ? Im posting a screen-shot which I have taken while working on Excel 2007.

[image]

Comment: I can not specificly help you as I am not using this configuration, but for other windows applications i needed to download specific fonts. Maybe this is required here too. On the other hand, did the windows help ever help you? Never worked for me :)

Comment: Sometime ! yes. But the more important question is why it is not working and how can i get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I needed to install Internet Explorer 8. I think this was the dependency that needed to be fixed.

```
 Use winetrick's own built-in installation feature to install IE8
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any real information, I have two guesses:

1. You're missing fonts that it requires. There are a couple of ways to install them. The first is to open up winetricks (which I think ships with Wine now, but if not `sudo apt-get install winetricks`) and find `msttcorefonts` and install it. The other is through the multiverse Ubuntu repos. Make sure multiverse is enabled in the package manager, then run `sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts`. Restart Office and Wine and see if it works.
2. The other guess is that it's running what can be described in layman's terms as a stripped-down browser. In which case, it may need either `libgecko` or (probably more likely) some libraries for Internet Explorer. [This answer has a number of different ways to obtain these libraries.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64788/how-to-install-ms-internet-explorer-7-8-or-9) I would probably try the easiest of them, first, with `winetricks ie8` and see where that gets you.