# How can I test with Internet Explorer while on my Ubuntu?

Tags: browser, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install MS Internet Explorer 7, 8 or 9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64788/how-to-install-ms-internet-explorer-7-8-or-9)

I want to test my apps in ie7, ie8 and ie9
How can I do this on Ubuntu?